# jqmobi dynamically adding items to footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, footer, jqmobi

I need to dynamically add buttons to the navbar in jQMobi after an asynch call to retrieve the data. I'm using the append method, but it doesn't refresh the footer automatically after the appends are done. If I go back to the previous page and return to the page with the navbar again, the new buttons are showing. How do I refresh from js?

My function:

```
function createNavBar(categories) {
// remove any previous items, except for home
var elements = $('#event-footer').children().not('#navbar-home');
$(elements).remove(elements);

// add new items
for(var i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
{
    $('#event-footer').append('<a href="#event-home" class="icon home" data-transition="none">'+categories[i].get("Name")+'</a>');        
}
```

}

Comment: Found it. needed to add a call to $.ui.updateNavbarElements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ui method $.ui.updateNavbarElements() to do it?

try:

```
function createNavBar(categories) {
    // get home element
    var elements = [$('#navbar-home').get()];

    // add new items
    for(var i=0;i<categories.length;i++)
    {
        elements.push('<a href="#event-home" class="icon home" data-transition="none">'+categories[i].get("Name")+'</a>');        
    }

    $.ui.updateNavbarElements($(elements));
}
```

Cheer :)